# how to get msg box with two conditions in excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba

//Hello all, you will make my date if you do this for me.
I am using the below macro to open Hyperlinks present in the "J:J" column.  And added a MsgBox to loop it. If the user clicks on it, I will continue to next step.
I need "Yes" & "No" buttons on the MsgBox. If I click on Yes I should continue and if I click on No then I want to call another module, something like Sub refresh() . Thanks in advance.

```
Sub OpenLinks()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set LinkRng = Range("J1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In LinkRng.Cells
        Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
        Do
        If ie.readyState = 4 Then
            ie.Visible = False
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "OK"
    ie.Visible = True
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Sub OpenLinks()
    Dim LinkRng As Range
    Set LinkRng = Range("J1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    For Each cell In LinkRng.Cells
        If MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow
        Else
            Refresh
        End If
        Do
        If ie.readyState = 4 Then
            ie.Visible = False
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "OK"
    ie.Visible = True
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: `If i click on Yes i should continue and if i click on No then I want to called another module something like Sub refresh() ` Can you please provide a complete specification for this?

Comment: If i press "Yes" button then i want to continue to open urls. if i press "No" then i should call another module into this.

Comment: Yes... i want to continue with other cells too.. :) and I want to continue from next cell.

Comment: It's working fine after making changes.. thanks a lot @Macro Man :)